# WebSocket connection to 'ws://ws.pusherapp.com/app/...' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, chat, pusher

I have a problem with a package made for the Framework Laravel.
I would like to make a chat on my project to make people talk to each other.

The problem is when I try to access to my app on pusher, I receive these 2 error codes :

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://ws.pusherapp.com/app/my_app_key?protocol=7&client=js&version=2.2.4&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

pusher.js:12 Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4001,"message":"Could not find app by key my_app_key. Perhaps you're connecting to the wrong cluster."}}}
```

This package is called Confer (https://github.com/dazzz1er/confer).

All my files are correct but it doesn't work !
I'm on laravel 5.1

in config/services.php

```
'pusher' => [
  'public' => 'my_app_key',
  'secret' => 'my_secret_key',
  'app_id' => 'my_app_id'
]
```

my blade template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> My project - @yield('title') </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/sweetalert.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="/vendor/confer/css/confer.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="./js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="./js/jcarousel.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/jcarousel-basic.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../../js/sweetalert.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="homepage">

  @include('confer::confer')

  @include('sweet::alert')

  @include('layouts.includes.nav')

  @include('layouts.includes.header')

  @yield('content')

  @include('layouts.includes.footer')

  <script src="./js/pusher.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/moment.js"></script>

  @include('confer::js')

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help ! :)

EDIT : I receive a response, it's a difference between versions ! 
Can anyone give me help to convert Confer in Laravel 5 to Laravel 5.1 ? Thank you ! :)

Here is the complete demo in laravel 5 ! 
https://github.com/dazzz1er/confer-demo

Comment: Did you replace this `'public' => 'my_app_key',` with your app key and the other two items too?

Comment: Yes all keys are replaced and correct, I don't understand the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

If you're not from the US i think you need to change the cluster to "eu"
https://pusher.com/docs/clusters#/lang=php

Answer (score 0):

The error message here `Could not find app by key my_app_key` suggests that you haven't replaced those with your actual Pusher credentials, which you can find on your Pusher dashboard.

That error is thrown by the Pusher library when it isn't given valid credentials. If you've updated `config/services.php` correctly you may need to restart your server for the changes to take effect.

You need to change your `config/services.php` to use keys that you can find from the Pusher dashboard under the "App keys" section. For example:

[image]

Comment: I've already do this, it's not the problem (I've hidden my keys by security only in this message, but it's not because of that)

Comment: @Rayzor286 Did you ever figure this out? I got exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't pretend to copy the answers of others but I just wanted to share what worked for me. In the env file I hadn't configured **BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher** properly. Then I **checked the cluster** to be the same one as the one that was given to me when I created the pusher app in their website. You can also find the cluster name you were assigned to under the "App Keys" tab. Then I **restarted Chrome Web Browser** and finally I **restarted the server** by running valet restart. You might restart your server with a different command depending on your development enviroment.